# Generate publish.htm when publishing clickonce app using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce

If you publish a Clickonce application from within visual studio, it will generate publish.htm .This seems to be Visual Studio generated, and not part of the publish target if the app is built with msbuild from a command line.

How do people handle automatic(e.g. as part of a build server) clickonce publishing, including a publish.htm ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild is not generating publish web page (ClickOnce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011427/msbuild-is-not-generating-publish-web-page-clickonce)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a target that escaped the characters for msbuild, and generates the publish.htm file on the fly.  No need to setup external dependencies on 3rd party build task assemblies :D  The only thing to consider is which frameworks your application is truly dependent upon.  If you force a targeted version of something higher than 3.5, you will need to update this task accordingly.  This structure also assumes you are using msbuild version 4.0 (aka ToolsVersion="4.0").

```
<PropertyGroup>

  <Title>YourTitle</Title>

  <PublisherName>YourPublisherName</PublisherName>

  <Company>YourCompanyName</Company>

  <ApplicationName>YourAppName</ApplicationName>

  <VersionNumber>YourVersionNumber</VersionNumber>

</PropertyGroup>



<ItemGroup>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CHTML%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CHEAD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTITLE%3E$(Title)%3C%2FTITLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CMETA HTTP-EQUIV%3D%22Content-Type%22 CONTENT%3D%22text%2Fhtml%3B charset%3Dutf-8%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSTYLE TYPE%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21--"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="BODY%7Bmargin-top%3A20px%3B margin-left%3A20px%3B margin-right%3A20px%3B color%3A%23000000%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B background-color%3Awhite%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="A%3Alink %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23000066%3B text-decoration%3Anone%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="A%3Avisited %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23000066%3B text-decoration%3Anone%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="A%3Aactive %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B text-decoration%3Anone%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="A%3Ahover %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23FF6600%3B text-decoration%3Anone%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="P %7Bmargin-top%3A0px%3B margin-bottom%3A12px%3B color%3A%23000000%3B font-family%3ATahoma%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="PRE %7Bborder-right%3A%23f0f0e0 1px solid%3B padding-right%3A5px%3B border-top%3A%23f0f0e0 1px solid%3B margin-top%3A-5px%3B padding-left%3A5px%3B font-size%3Ax-small%3B padding-bottom%3A5px%3B border-left%3A%23f0f0e0 1px solid%3B padding-top%3A5px%3B border-bottom%3A%23f0f0e0 1px solid%3B font-family%3ACourier New%3B background-color%3A%23e5e5cc%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="TD %7Bfont-size%3A12px%3B color%3A%23000000%3B font-family%3ATahoma%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="H2 %7Bborder-top%3A %23003366 1px solid%3B margin-top%3A25px%3B font-weight%3Abold%3B font-size%3A1.5em%3B margin-bottom%3A10px%3B margin-left%3A-15px%3B color%3A%23003366%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="H3 %7Bmargin-top%3A10px%3B font-size%3A 1.1em%3B margin-bottom%3A 10px%3B margin-left%3A -15px%3B color%3A %23000000%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="UL %7Bmargin-top%3A10px%3B margin-left%3A20px%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="OL %7Bmargin-top%3A10px%3B margin-left%3A20px%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="LI %7Bmargin-top%3A10px%3B color%3A %23000000%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="FONT.value %7Bfont-weight%3Abold%3B color%3Adarkblue%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="FONT.key %7Bfont-weight%3A bold%3B color%3A darkgreen%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".divTag %7Bborder%3A1px%3B border-style%3Asolid%3B background-color%3A%23FFFFFF%3B text-decoration%3Anone%3B height%3Aauto%3B width%3Aauto%3B background-color%3A%23cecece%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".BannerColumn %7Bbackground-color%3A%23000000%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".Banner %7Bborder%3A0%3B padding%3A0%3B height%3A8px%3B margin-top%3A0px%3B color%3A%23ffffff%3B filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType%3D1,StartColorStr%3D'%231c5280',EndColorStr%3D'%23FFFFFF')%3B%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".BannerTextCompany %7Bfont%3Abold%3B font-size%3A18pt%3B color%3A%23cecece%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B height%3A0px%3B margin-top%3A0%3B margin-left%3A8px%3B margin-bottom%3A0%3B padding%3A0px%3B white-space%3Anowrap%3B filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX%3D2,OffY%3D2,Color%3D'black',Positive%3D'true')%3B%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".BannerTextApplication %7Bfont%3Abold%3B font-size%3A18pt%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B height%3A0px%3B margin-top%3A0%3B margin-left%3A8px%3B margin-bottom%3A0%3B padding%3A0px%3B white-space%3Anowrap%3B filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX%3D2,OffY%3D2,Color%3D'black',Positive%3D'true')%3B%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".BannerText %7Bfont%3Abold%3B font-size%3A18pt%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B height%3A0px%3B margin-top%3A0%3B margin-left%3A8px%3B margin-bottom%3A0%3B padding%3A0px%3B filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX%3D2,OffY%3D2,Color%3D'black',Positive%3D'true')%3B%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".BannerSubhead %7Bborder%3A0%3B padding%3A0%3B height%3A16px%3B margin-top%3A0px%3B margin-left%3A10px%3B color%3A%23ffffff%3B filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType%3D1,StartColorStr%3D'%234B3E1A',EndColorStr%3D'%23FFFFFF')%3B%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".BannerSubheadText %7Bfont%3Abold%3B height%3A11px%3B font-size%3A11px%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B margin-top%3A1%3B margin-left%3A10%3B filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX%3D2,OffY%3D2,Color%3D'black',Positive%3D'true')%3B%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".FooterRule %7Bborder%3A0%3B padding%3A0%3B height%3A1px%3B margin%3A0px%3B color%3A%23ffffff%3B filter%3Aprogid%3ADXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType%3D1,StartColorStr%3D'%234B3E1A',EndColorStr%3D'%23FFFFFF')%3B%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".FooterText %7Bfont-size%3A11px%3B font-weight%3Anormal%3B text-decoration%3Anone%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B margin-top%3A10%3B margin-left%3A0px%3B margin-bottom%3A2%3B padding%3A0px%3B color%3A%23999999%3B white-space%3Anowrap%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".FooterText A%3Alink %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23999999%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".FooterText A%3Avisited %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23999999%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".FooterText A%3Aactive %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23999999%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".FooterText A%3Ahover %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23FF6600%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".ClickOnceInfoText %7Bfont-size%3A11px%3B font-weight%3Anormal%3B text-decoration%3Anone%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B margin-top%3A0%3B margin-right%3A2px%3B margin-bottom%3A0%3B padding%3A0px%3B color%3A%23000000%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".InstallTextStyle %7Bfont%3Abold%3B font-size%3A14pt%3B font-family%3ATahoma%3B a%3A%23FF0000%3B text-decoration%3ANone%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".DetailsStyle %7Bmargin-left%3A30px%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".ItemStyle %7Bmargin-left%3A-15px%3B font-weight%3Abold%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".StartColorStr %7Bbackground-color%3A%234B3E1A%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".JustThisApp A%3Alink %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23000066%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".JustThisApp A%3Avisited %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23000066%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".JustThisApp A%3Aactive %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include=".JustThisApp A%3Ahover %7Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3B color%3A%23FF6600%3B text-decoration%3Aunderline%7D"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="--%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FSTYLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FHEAD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CBODY%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE WIDTH%3D%22100%%22 CELLPADDING%3D%220%22 CELLSPACING%3D%222%22 BORDER%3D%220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- Begin Banner --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE CELLPADDING%3D%222%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22 BGCOLOR%3D%22%23cecece%22 WIDTH%3D%22100%%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE BGCOLOR%3D%22%231c5280%22 WIDTH%3D%22100%%22 CELLPADDING%3D%220%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD CLASS%3D%22Banner%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD CLASS%3D%22Banner%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPAN CLASS%3D%22BannerTextCompany%22%3E$(Company)%3C%2FSPAN%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD CLASS%3D%22Banner%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPAN CLASS%3D%22BannerTextApplication%22%3E$(ApplicationName)%3C%2FSPAN%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD CLASS%3D%22Banner%22 ALIGN%3D%22RIGHT%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- End Banner --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- Begin Dialog --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD ALIGN%3D%22LEFT%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE CELLPADDING%3D%222%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22 WIDTH%3D%22540%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD WIDTH%3D%22496%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- Begin AppInfo --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD COLSPAN%3D%223%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CB%3EName%3A%3C%2FB%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD WIDTH%3D%225%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 WIDTH%3D%2210%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E$(ApplicationName)%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD COLSPAN%3D%223%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CB%3EVersion%3A%3C%2FB%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD WIDTH%3D%225%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 WIDTH%3D%2210%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E$(VersionNumber)%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD COLSPAN%3D%223%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CB%3EPublisher%3A%3C%2FB%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD WIDTH%3D%225%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 WIDTH%3D%2210%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E$(Publisher)%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3Ctr%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3Ctd colspan%3D%223%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Ftd%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2Ftr%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- End AppInfo --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- Begin Prerequisites --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE ID%3D%22BootstrapperSection%22 BORDER%3D%220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD COLSPAN%3D%222%22%3EThe following prerequisites are required%3A%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD WIDTH%3D%2210%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CUL%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CLI%3EWindows Installer 3.1%3C%2FLI%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CLI%3E.NET Framework 3.5 SP1%3C%2FLI%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CLI%3E.NET Framework 3.0 (x86)%3C%2FLI%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CLI%3E.NET Framework 3.5%3C%2FLI%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FUL%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD COLSPAN%3D%222%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="If these components are already installed, you can %3CSPAN CLASS%3D%22JustThisApp%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CA HREF%3D%22CsodOfflinePlayer.application%22%3Elaunch%3C%2FA%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FSPAN%3E the application now. Otherwise, click the button below to install the prerequisites and run the application."/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD COLSPAN%3D%222%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- End Prerequisites --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- Begin Buttons --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD ALIGN%3D%22LEFT%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE CELLPADDING%3D%222%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22 WIDTH%3D%22540%22 STYLE%3D%22cursor%3Ahand%22 ONCLICK%3D%22window.navigate(InstallButton.href)%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD ALIGN%3D%22LEFT%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE CELLPADDING%3D%221%22 BGCOLOR%3D%22%23333333%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE CELLPADDING%3D%221%22 BGCOLOR%3D%22%23cecece%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE CELLPADDING%3D%221%22 BGCOLOR%3D%22%23efefef%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD WIDTH%3D%2220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 WIDTH%3D%2220%22 HEIGHT%3D%221%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CA ID%3D%22InstallButton%22 HREF%3D%22setup.exe%22%3EInstall%3C%2FA%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD width%3D%2220%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 WIDTH%3D%2220%22 HEIGHT%3D%221%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD WIDTH%3D%2215%%22 ALIGN%3D%22right%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- End Buttons --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- End Dialog --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- Spacer Row --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- Begin Footer --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTABLE WIDTH%3D%22100%%22 CELLPADDING%3D%220%22 CELLSPACING%3D%220%22 BORDER%3D%220%22 BGCOLOR%3D%22%23ffffff%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD HEIGHT%3D%225%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 HEIGHT%3D%225%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD CLASS%3D%22FooterText%22 ALIGN%3D%22center%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CA HREF%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkId%3D154571%22%3EClickOnce and .NET Framework Resources%3C%2FA%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD HEIGHT%3D%225%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 HEIGHT%3D%225%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CTD HEIGHT%3D%221%22 bgcolor%3D%22%23cecece%22%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3CSPACER TYPE%3D%22block%22 HEIGHT%3D%221%22 %2F%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%21-- End Footer --%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTD%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTR%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%20"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FTABLE%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FBODY%3E"/>

  <PublishHtmFileContents Include="%3C%2FHTML%3E"/>

</ItemGroup>



<WriteLinesToFile Lines="@(PublishHtmFileContents)" File="publish.htm" Overwrite="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm trying to push this off to a separate file and load it in, now I just need those expressions to get reevaluated. Ended up posting a new SO question for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639470/how-to-re-run-property-evaluation-in-msbuild-target

Answer (score 0):

I use batch scripts with mage.exe to create my manifests and publish page.  Updating the publish.htm page is trivial.  There's a section in the HTML file that looks like this:

```
<!-- Begin AppInfo -->
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="3">&nbsp;</TD></TR><TR><TD><B>Name:</B></TD>
<TD WIDTH="5"><SPACER TYPE="block" WIDTH="10" /></TD><TD>AppName</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="3">&nbsp;</TD></TR><TR><TD><B>Version:</B></TD>
<TD WIDTH="5"><SPACER TYPE="block" WIDTH="10" /></TD><TD>1.0.0.0</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="3">&nbsp;</TD></TR><TR><TD><B>Publisher:</B></TD>
<TD WIDTH="5"><SPACER TYPE="block" WIDTH="10" /></TD>
<TD>AppPublisher</TD>
</TR>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</TABLE>
<!-- End AppInfo -->
```

In my scripts, I just have that "basic" publish.htm file as a template, and I do string search/replacement for AppName, 1.0.0.0, and AppPublisher with whatever values I want to plug in.

Also, if you're not familiar with mage.exe, I'd check out MageUI first, then get your mage.exe scripts written (if you're going to be doing this more than once or twice).

Comment: What does mage.exe do vs building the Publish target on the project via msbuild ?