# ClickOnce: How to publish additional files to the *server* along with the Publish.htm, Setup.exe, etc...?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, publishing

I'd like to know if it's possible to have the Publish mechanism copy additional files to the destination of the installation folder along with the Setup.exe.

By default Publish publishes the following files:

- Application Files (folder)
- app.manifest
- publish.htm
- setup.exe

I would like to have Visual Studio publish a bunch of other files from the solution in that folder, along with those standard files. To be clear, I want these extra files in the **server**, i don't want them deployed to the client.

Is this possible?

Comment: I want to do this as well.  I wonder if there is any post-publish event that we can hook onto.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no. The server basically serves up all of the files that you publish and they, in turn, are deployed to the client. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way.

Answer (score 0):

The tips in [Generate publish.htm when publishing clickonce app using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101037/generate-publish-htm-when-publishing-clickonce-app-using-msbuild) might be useful.  I suspect that this can be done using a Customization file and msbuild to do the ClickOnce publish instead of VS2010.  See http://wallism.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/clickonce-creating-publish-page-from-msbuild/.  If anyone knows the answer it might be this ClickOnce expert.

It is still not clear whether you can get the msbuild to throw in the extra files, but if you are already running Publish from the command line, a script to FTP the extra files might do the trick.