# MSBuild is not generating publish web page (ClickOnce)

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, clickonce, publish

I am facing a problem that when I publish my ClickOnce application through MSBuild (4.0), the **publish.htm** (or default.htm) isn't created in the app.publish folder.

When publishing through Visual Studio, it gets crated...

In my .csproj file I have the following properties set, and it still not working...

```
<CreateWebPageOnPublish>true</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
<WebPage>default.htm</WebPage>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://codemonkeyking.blogspot.com/2009/04/nantmsbuild-clickonce-publishing.html  this is someone claimed that this is the solution and also then discovered that it's not

Answer (score 3):

I found a good solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/40bb7d32-a9ad-40d7-8113-cb3ed2747e69/publishing-a-clickonce-project-with-commandline-msbuild?forum=msbuild). You can use a template for publish.htm with **{VERSION}** placeholder inside. [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) are required for the FileUpdate task.

**BUILD_VERSION** - environment variable, set by my build script. **PublishDir** property is set in argument for msbuild.

```
  <!-- .... -->

  <Target Name="DoPublish">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFileName)" Targets="Publish" Properties="ApplicationVersion=$(BUILD_VERSION)" />
    <!-- Write publish.htm file for ClickOnce -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\publish.htm" DestinationFiles="$(PublishDir)\publish.htm"/>
    <FileUpdate Files="$(PublishDir)\publish.htm"
                IgnoreCase="true"
                Multiline="true" 
                Singleline="false"
                Regex="{VERSION}" 
                ReplacementText="$(BUILD_VERSION)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: I'll test it in my next project, but it seems to be a very good solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Does this mean that the value of BUILD_VERSION will have to be manually specified for each deployment in the pipeline and also manually incremented?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio does not control it. The environment variable should be specified. I calculate it automatically by Git tags similarly to the GitVersion project.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, but otherwise had what sounds like the same or similar issue. The solution was to open the Properties of the Project file in Visual Studio > Go to the "Publish" settings, and in the right pane, click <kbd>Options...</kbd>. This will open up the "Publish Options" dialog. Select "Deployment" and if you see the "Deployment web page" is empty (mine was) then enter "publish.htm". You should then be able to check "Automatically generate deployment web page after every publish" (you need to check this). Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the dialog and then republish. Your "publish.htm" file should now appear.

Comment: It works only for publishing through Visual Studio. But it doesn't work if you [use command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2017).