# Creating publish.htm from msbuild in a .proj file

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce

I have a proj file with a step in it that builds a specific csproj, with the Publish target so it generates the clickonce artifacts:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" 
         Properties="Configuration=Release" 
         ContinueOnError="false" 
         Targets="Publish">
</MSBuild>
```

This works, but it's only generating the

```
Application Files\
setup.exe
MyApplication.application
MyApplication.exe
```

I also need the `publish.htm` so when it's navigated to it can display the install page.

How do I generate this publish.htm from within my msbuild project file? If I use visual studio to publish my app to a target directory, it creates the publish.htm. So I'd need to replicate this from my msbuild project file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild is not generating publish web page (ClickOnce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011427/msbuild-is-not-generating-publish-web-page-clickonce)