# Azure DevOps ClickOnce Build&Release publish.htm missing

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, clickonce

at the moment I am trying to build and release a ClickOnce application on a subfolder of an Azure AppService.
So far, the deployment of the binaries works quite well. At the moment what is missing is the pulish.htm, which provides the download page for the ClickOnce application.

As build arguments I hand over the following:

```
/target:publish /p:ApplicationVersion=$(AssemblyVersion) /p:PublishURL=http://[URL_to_ClickOnce-Download] /p:UpdateEnabled=true /p:UpdateMode=Foreground /p:CreateWebPageOnPublish=true /p:WebPage="publish.htm" /p:IsWebBootstrapper=true
```

What i am mostly missing is a documentation of the allowed/possible build arguments in the MSBuild-task in Azure Devops. That's the reason why I am asking here - has anyone an idea what am I missing here?

In case you need additional information, please don't hesitate to ask me.

Thank you very much in advance and kind regards

mdie80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is solution in below similar thread.

[MSBuild is not generating publish web page (ClickOnce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011427/msbuild-is-not-generating-publish-web-page-clickonce/44112031)

According to above solution, You need to define a custom Msbuild target in your .csproj file to copy the publish.htm to the publish folder. And in your pipeline msbuild task specify the target to the custom target (ie. `/target:DoPublish`) to the arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will give it a try and give feedback!

Comment: Hi @mdie Did you get a chance to try it out. How did it go?

Comment: Hi Levi, so far I hadn't have the chance to try it out, as I had a sick leave, i will try today and give you feedback, thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi again Levi, actually it worked with your suggestion. Thank you very much. I marked your answer as solution in this thread.