# How to re-run property evaluation in MSBuild target?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I have a custom MSBuild target, partial snippet as follows ..

```
<Target Name="PublishHtm">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishHtmTemplateContents>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(PublishHtmTemplatePath)))</PublishHtmTemplateContents>
    <PublishHtm>$(PublishHtmTemplateContents)</PublishHtm>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <WriteLinesToFile Lines="$(PublishHtm)" File="$(PublishDir)\publish.htm" Overwrite="true"/>
</Target>
```

This is a rework attempt for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019806/11398) in that I'm trying to isolate this template to an external file. The template contains MSBuild property references such as `$(ApplicationName)`. When doing this exactly as described in the [linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019806/11398), it works fine, but when loading the template in as a string, none of these property expressions are evaluated by the time it gets to the file.

```
<SPAN CLASS="BannerTextApplication">$(ApplicationName)</SPAN>
```

Is there an MSBuild expression/function I can use to get the string to be reevaluated given the context that the Target is being invoked?

BTW I'd rather *not* work around the problem using find/replace or regex replace, and stick with the MSBuild expression engine.

Using Visual Studio 2012 & .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: You should place the property/item declaration *inside a target*. See dynamic properties and items at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419659.aspx.

Comment: You're loading this template from external file. This means msbuild engine won't do any property expansion in the template iteself. So your $(PublishHtmTemplateContents) is just a text string read from file. And you simply re-assigning it to $(PublishHtm) as a text value. Engine doesn't work this way.You can try to wrap template in some form of target in the separate file and then build it using msbuild task.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi, looking up at my question I'm reading my property declaration from within the target node, and your article has me suffering from TL;DR as there's TMI in MSBuild. What are you getting at? Can you summarize an elaboration?

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak I am well aware that MSBuild doesn't exactly work this way, which is why I posted the question. (Actually, it *does* work except for the late-loaded expressions which need re-evaluation.) Can you elaborate on your "You can try to.." verbiage as a proposed Answer ?

Comment: FYI guys, if you follow the hyperlink for the words "this solution" in my question, you can see what I started out with, and I already know that that method does work, as I made clear in my question text. I'm trying to establish a different way, one that doesn't explicitly declare the HTML markup inside the MSBuild XML. In other words, I'm not happy with the normal constraints and I am looking for an MSBuild API call or something that will let me get around them without being workaround-ish in form.

Comment: It'd help if you can add some samples we can play with - given that you're not using "this" solution as is - this question is lacking some "meat" to trial and error potential solutions. What would help : simplified current template html, sample of desired output and base build script you're using. Also it'd be good to know what limitations you want to apply - no regex is clear, what's about C# coded inline tasks or external libraries for msbuild ?

Comment: I *am* using that exact sample, for that exact purpose. Start with that other SO post, then URL-decode into a file. I don't want that publish.htm template proposed in the other SO article all munged up in URL-encoded XML attributes, untweakable, unreadable, so I pushed it off to a normal .html file with $(..) msbuild property placeholders still in place. What I'm looking for if it exists would be something like <TemplateHtm>$([MsBuild]::Evaluate($(TemplateHtmSource)))</TemplateHtm> but of course that specifically doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for not getting back to this question for awhile.
Initially I thought that to solve this problem we'll need to bend MSBuild in very unusual way (plan for today was to write complex inline task which will do regex-replace in external file using Msbuild properties as tokens ). But I think this can be solved easier, using CDATA section, which is valid inside property definition:

Here is main script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyOtherProperty>$([System.DateTime]::Now)</MyOtherProperty>
        <Version>1.0.1b</Version>
        <ProjectName>MSBuild Rox</ProjectName>
        <Author>Alexey Shcherbak</Author>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PropsToPass Include="MyOtherProperty=$(MyOtherProperty)" />
            <PropsToPass Include="Version=$(Version)" />
            <PropsToPass Include="ProjectName=$(ProjectName)" />
            <PropsToPass Include="Author=$(Author)" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <MSBuild Projects="TransformHTML.Template.proj" Properties="@(PropsToPass)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And here is your template. It's not pure html, it's still msbuild file, but at least without ugly encoding for html tags in xml. It's just a block in CDATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Transform">
    <PropertyGroup>
            <HtmlProperty><![CDATA[
                <body>
                    <div>$(MyOtherProperty)</div>
                    <div>$(Version)</div>
                    <div>$(ProjectName)</div>
                    <div>$(Author)</div>
                </body>
            ]]></HtmlProperty>
        </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Transform">
        <Message Text="HtmlProperty: $(HtmlProperty)" Importance="High" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Maybe it's not very elegant ( I personally don't like the section with @PropsToPass) but it'll do the job. You can put everything inline into single file and then you don't need to pass properties to MSBuild task. I don't like massive html-encoding from proposed "this solution" but I'd rather prefer to keep HTML template in the same script where it'll be transformed, just in nice html format, without encoding.

Single file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyOtherProperty>$([System.DateTime]::Now)</MyOtherProperty>
        <Version>1.0.1b</Version>
        <ProjectName>MSBuild Rox</ProjectName>
        <Author>Alexey Shcherbak</Author>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <HtmlProperty><![CDATA[
                <body>
                    <div>$(MyOtherProperty)</div>
                    <div>$(Version)</div>
                    <div>$(ProjectName)</div>
                    <div>$(Author)</div>
                </body>
            ]]></HtmlProperty>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <Message Text="HtmlProperty: $(HtmlProperty)" Importance="High" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

You can also [download these files here](https://github.com/centur/msbuild.box)

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer the question (apparently it's *not possible*?? to re-evaluate externalized MSBuild properties like I was asking), your answer does address my immediate concern of having unmanagable HTML in MSBuild output script, so thanks.

Comment: From my understanding there is no direct way to re-evaluate script body (including property) in the current msbuild context. But it might be worth to check msbuild source code to confirm or disprove that =)

Comment: Unfortunately, somehow your proposed approach doesn't retain its content to detail. Semicolons are getting dropped in CSS, for example. 
I still expect that what I'm looking for is still going to be doable if I generate a .targets file and invoke `<MSBuild Project="generatedfile" Targets="ProcessHtml">`, or something. Not there yet.

Comment: Actually, reverting to the original solution drops semicolons from the style tag, too. Seems to be a weird matter from the WriteLinesToFile task. Replacing all semicolons with %3b worked (yes even though we're in a CDATA).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Eval task

```
<Target Name="PublishHtm">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishHtmTemplateContents>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(PublishHtmTemplatePath)))</PublishHtmTemplateContents>
    <Eval Values="$(PublishHtmTemplateContents)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="EvalItemTemp"/>
    </Eval>
    <PublishHtm>%(EvalItemTemp.Identity)</PublishHtm>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <WriteLinesToFile Lines="$(PublishHtm)" File="$(PublishDir)\publish.htm" Overwrite="true"/>
</Target>
```

Actually the task does nothing except returning exactly the same value it received, however when you pass the returned value %(EvalItemTemp.Identity) to anywhere, msbuild does evaluation!

Eval task source:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == 'Current' OR $(MSBuildToolsVersion.Split('.')[0]) &gt;= 14">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TasksAssemblyName>Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll</TasksAssemblyName>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TasksAssemblyName>Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll</TasksAssemblyName>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
  <UsingTask TaskName="Eval" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\$(TasksAssemblyName)">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Values ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="True" Output="False" />
      <Result ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="False" Output="True" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Class" Language="cs" Source="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)TaskSource\EvalTask.cs"/>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
</Project>
```

Where TaskSource\EvalTask.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Varonis.MSBuild.Tasks
{
    public class Eval : Task
    {

        [Required]
        public ITaskItem[] Values { get; set; }
        [Output]
        public ITaskItem[] Result { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Result = new TaskItem[Values.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length; i++)
            {
                Result[i] = new TaskItem(Values[i].ItemSpec);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```